# how set spinner from previous selected value using spinner object?

Tags: android, android-spinner, custom-adapter

```
CustomeSpinerAdapter jobAdapter = new CustomeSpinerAdapter(
            getApplicationContext(), R.layout.custom_spiner_row,
            jobListData);

    spJobType.setAdapter(jobAdapter);
```

here i want to set `spiner.setseleciton(position);` with value pair 
my previous value form the data base is `jobID=44`

Answer (score 0):

i think the best practice for this solution is the SharedPrefrences Class.

```
SharedPrefrences AppData = PrefrencesManager.getDefaultSharedPrefrences(this);
AppData.edit().putString("prevSpinnerValue",jobID);
```

and for getting there is simple snippet too:

```
AppData.getString("prevSpinnerValue",null);
```

and set the selected item of your spinner to above value that you get from prefs.

maybe this help.